# Disable Google Assistant Gesture

Tags: miui, google-assistant

Im using Miui 12.5 in my Redmi 9, and for navigation im using gestures(swipe up for menu, swipe from corners to center to go back, etc), but sometimes when swiping up, instead of going back to home screen it shows the google assistant(like in the image) and i could not find where to turn this off. How can i disable this behavior?

[image]

Comment: Interesting, on my Pixel device back is swiping on the left or right display edge towards center. Swiping from one of the lower corners towards center is for the assistant.

Comment: Just to be sure, have you searched for "gesture" in the Android settings?

Comment: @AndrewT. yes, it just shows the options for miui gestures